# What exactly do these cloud architecture terms mean?

Tags: cloud-computing, cloud

What exactly does `Hosted-Application`, `Cloud-Enabled`, `Cloud-Native` and `Cloud-Agnostic` mean? Pros, Cons, and when to use?

Unable to find a similar question on Stack Exchange.

Comment: In what context?

Comment: Those are mostly marketing buzzwords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Hosted-Application`

Means it doesn't primarily run on the users computer. It runs on someone else's. This saves the cost of maintaining it locally at the expense of the privacy and control lost by hosting it remotely.

> Application Hosting is most commonly offered as Software as a Service (SaaS) subscription which allows businesses to run their applications on servers or in a cloud that is hosted by a service provider such as AWS (Amazon Web Services) and GCP (Google Cloud Platform).
>
> [Dialogic - What is Application Hosting?](https://www.dialogic.com/glossary/application-hosting)

`Cloud-Enabled`

Means it's ready to run on someone else's computer while the users computer connects to it to use it.

> Cloud-enabled usually refers to applications built traditionally and then migrated to the cloud. These applications were originally designed in a monolithic fashion and depend on local resources and hardware.
>
> [papertrail.com - Cloud-Based, Cloud-Native, and Cloud-Enabled Applications—What’s the Difference?](https://www.papertrail.com/solution/tips/cloud-based-cloud-native-and-cloud-enabled-applications-whats-the-difference/#:%7E:text=Cloud%2Denabled%20usually%20refers%20to,on%20local%20resources%20and%20hardware.)

`Cloud-Native`

Means it was originally written with the cloud in mind. Not simply ported over to it after versions that ran locally.

> Cloud native is the software approach of building, deploying, and managing modern applications in cloud computing environments. Modern companies want to build highly scalable, flexible, and resilient applications that they can update quickly to meet customer demands.
>
> [Amazon AWS - What is Cloud Native?](https://aws.amazon.com/what-is/cloud-native/#:%7E:text=Cloud%20native%20is%20the%20software,quickly%20to%20meet%20customer%20demands.)

`Cloud-Agnostic`

Means it doesn't care which cloud you run it on. Also means it doesn't use any specialized features only available on a particular cloud. This becomes an issue if you decide to switch cloud providers and your app isn't agnostic.

> Cloud agnostic refers to a cloud design strategy in which applications, tools, and services are designed to migrate seamlessly between multiple cloud platforms or between on-premises and cloud in a hybrid model without disruption of service.
>
> [VMware Tanzu - What is cloud agnostic?](https://tanzu.vmware.com/cloud-agnostic#:%7E:text=Cloud%20agnostic%20refers%20to%20a,model%20without%20disruption%20of%20service.)

While Doc Brown is absolutely correct that these are marketing buzzwords they are successful buzzwords. What they are accomplishing is nothing less than the recentralization of computing that we haven't seen since the personal computer made mainframes largely irrelevant. They are making the PC into the new dumb terminal.